# Passing a vector by const rerefence and adding an element to the vector

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to understand the following member function:

```
void Date::setDays(const std::vector<Date> &days){
  Date d(1, 1, 1);
  m_days = days;
  m_days.push_back(d); // valid.
  days.push_back(d); // invalid.
}
```

In the member function above that belongs to the class `Date`, I'm passing `days` by reference as a const. I can understand why it is illegal to add an element to `days` as it is `const`. However, my confusion is, how is it possible that I can add an element to `m_days`? Doesn't it refer to the same vector as `days`? When I add an element to `m_days`, does it mean I'm adding an element to `days` too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do ‘value semantics’ and ‘pointer semantics’ mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166033/what-do-value-semantics-and-pointer-semantics-mean)

Comment: @L.F. It didn't help me. In fact it was just more confusing.

Comment: Pay special attention to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/166048).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign `m_days` a *copy* of `days`. It is *not* the same vector and if `m_days` is not `const` (which it obviously is not since you just assigned to it) then adding elements to it is just fine. Nothing you do to `m_days` affects `days` in any way.

Comment: The reason why this happens is because of the implementation of the assignment operator in vector?

Comment: @swdon No. That is what normally happens when you use `=`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166033/what-do-value-semantics-and-pointer-semantics-mean/166048#166048

Answer (score 2):

`m_days = days` makes a **copy** of the `days` array, i.e. `m_days` is another vector independent of `days` which has a copy of the `days` array. Any changes that you make to `m_days` will not affect `days`. Hence, the constness of `days` is not violated.