# Java vs C++ (Call-By-Reference?)

Tags: java, c++, pass-by-reference, call-by-value

I am not sure if this topic is about Call-By-Reference but I have a question about these 2 snippets:

**Java**

```
public static int calculateWinner(int[][] game){
        game[0][0] = 5; 
.
.
.
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] game = {
            {1, 2, 2},
            {2, 1, 2},
            {1, 1, 1}
        };

        int winner = calculateWinner(game);
.
.
.
}
```

**C++**

```
int calculateWinner(array<array<int, 3>, 3> field) {
    field[0][0] = 5;
.
.
.
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

    array<array<int, 3>, 3> field;
    field[0] = { 2, 0, 1 };
    field[1] = { 0, 1, 0 };
    field[2] = { 1, 0, 2 };

    int winner = calculateWinner(field);
.
.
.
}
```

So if I print out the array in the main method, why is it in Java that my array at position [0][0] is 5 but in C++ it's not?
I learned that in C++ it's a copy only in the scope. 
What exactly is the difference?

Comment: One `=` is assignment, two `==` is a boolean equality test. `field[0][0] == 5;` is **not** `field[0][0] = 5;`

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  In such a book they will discuss the difference between pass by value and pass by reference.

Comment: Sorry that's a typo... It should be = but still my question is the same.

Comment: Even with field[0][0] = 5; in C++ it doesn't change the value

Comment: `int calculateWinner(array<array<int, 3>, 3> field)` is pass by value.  If you wanted to pass by reference, you would do `int calculateWinner(array<array<int, 3>, 3>& field)`. It's unclear, to me, what, exactly, are you asking about.

Comment: related/maybe dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166033/what-do-value-semantics-and-pointer-semantics-mean

Comment: Sounds like you already know the answer? "*I learned that in C++ it's a copy only in the scope*"

Comment: I'm not sure if that was correct though. I started to learn C++ last week and had not learn '&' yet.

Comment: No matter how you slice it, both C and its variants and Java are call by value.  The fact that you can pass addresses and references and pointers is irrelevant.

Comment: So Java is pass-by-reference and in my example with C++ it is pass-by-value?

Comment: Related: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: @Haidepzai No.  java is always pass by value.  If you pass a reference can you actually change the reference?  Nope!  You can only change what it refers too.

Comment: Thanks... This is still so complicated for me. If I pass by value, then why does the array in the main method in Java changed?

Comment: Because you are passing in a reference to that.  You are changing what it points to which is fine but you can't change the reference itself  Even in C you can pass an address to a method via pointer and change what the address points to by, but you can't change the pointer unless you pass in its address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted above, the main problem here is that by default, the parameters are passed as values and not references. It is true in Java as well, however, whatever passed in the java snippet is the **pointer** to the array, and not the array itself, making it seem as "pass by reference", **however**, Java is always ***passing by value***!

In C++ it is possible to pass both by value and by reference. You can pass a pointer to an object, which is a *new* section in the program's memory, which contains the location to the wanted value, or you can pass the reference to the specific position in the memory in which the value is stored. Notice the *memory addresses* of the pointer in the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int num)
{
    std::cout << "The location of pass-by-value num is: " << &num << std::endl;
}

void foo1(int* num)
{
    std::cout << "The location of num* is: " << &num << " But its value is :" << num << std::endl;
}

void foo2(int& num)
{
    std::cout << "The location of num& is: " << &num << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int num;

    std::cout << "The location of num is: " << &num << std::endl;

    foo(num);
    foo1(&num);
    foo2(num);
}
```

The output of this snippet is:

```
The location of num is: 0x7ffce8cceccc

The location of pass-by-value num is: 0x7ffce8ccecac

The location of num* is: 0x7ffce8cceca8 But its value is :0x7ffce8cceccc

The location of num& is: 0x7ffce8cceccc
```

In foo we pass the *value* of the integer, therefore, we get a different address than the original.

In foo1, we pass the value of a *pointer* to num. The pointer has its own memory location, and its **value** is the memory address of num.

In foo2, we pass the **reference** to the integer num, and its memory address is **exactly** the memory address of the original, and this is a **true** pass-by-reference.

In order to edit such an object, you need to pass it by-pointer, or by-reference (generally, pass-by-reference is preferred over pointers whenever possible).

Answer (score 1):

C++ has pass by reference and pass by copy.
Java has only pass by copy(But, the inner objects of the object point to the same reference as the original).

So:

```
static void nullReference(int a []){ 
   a = null; // the copy of the object points to null
}

static void update(int a []) { 
 a[0]=5; // [0] is from the original reference.
```

}

```
static void main (String args[]){ 
int a [] = {1,2,3}; 
nullReference(a); 
print(a == null); // false
update(a); 
print(a[0] == 5); // true
```