# How do I read this small program?

Tags: c++

I have been struggling to find out how increment operators relate to the value of b, c and the way reference sign changes the value when it is being written. The program prints out 8, but I am not sure what the reference actually does in this particular situation. Here is a code:

```
int fun1(int d) {
 ++d;
 return d++;
}
int fun2(int &d) {
 ++d;
 return d++;
}
int main(void) {
 int a = 1, b, c;
 b = fun1(a);
 c = fun2(b);
 cout << a + b + c << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code line by line and see how the values in the variables change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crux of your problem lie in this part of your code:

```
int fun1(int d) { }
int fun2(int &d) { }
```

The `int d` in the first function are [*value semantics*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166033/what-do-value-semantics-and-pointer-semantics-mean). This means that the value of the variable passed to function `fun1` is *copied* and only know inside of `fun1`.

The `int &d` are *reference semantics* which means that the variable passed to `fun2` is referenced by `d` and as such if you modify `d` inside of `fun2` the actual value of the variable passed to `fun2` is changed.

In your case this means that the value of `a` is copied by `fun1` while `fun2` updates the value of `b`. Because `d` is used in `fun2` as a [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) to the actual variable `b` wherein the value is stored.

And more to the point of the value of `8` printed by this program. `++d` is the pre-increment operator, `d++` is the post-increment operator. Meaning:

- pre-increment: increment `d` first then use the new value of `d`
- post-increment: keep the value of `d` and use that to do something and after that increment the value of `d`

Combining these things (value/reference semantics and the behaviour of pre/post increment) we get that that `fun1` and `fun2` return the original value of `d` which is incremented before the original value is returned. So `return d++;` is equivalent to this piece of code:

```
int returnvalue = d;
d = d + 1;
return returnvalue;
```

But because `fun2` has a reference `d` to the variable `b` in main, the value in `b` is incremented by one because `d` was post-incremented in `return d++`.

[ISOcpp value and reference semantics.](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/value-vs-ref-semantics) And [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in) about the difference between pointers and references in C++.

---

If you need a much larger explanation of these terms and what they mean, this [list of book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/8548828) recommendations is great. My choice would be A Tour of C++ by the creator of C++. It does a great job of going over everything you should now about C++ and is very cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Since the first answer didn't fully go into the example at hand, I'll elaborate on this, because it's, at first, a tricky subject IMO.

```
int a = 1, b, c;
```

This declares three int variables: `a`, `b` and `c`. It also initializes `a` with the value 1. `b` and `c` receive the default start value for ints, so 0.

As the first answer mentioned, `fun1(int d)` copies the value of the variable passed to it into a local variable, but does not alter the original variable. What's the matter with `++d` and `d++`, though? This got to do with the order in which operations get performed. `++d` takes the value of `d`, increases it by one, then assigns it back to `d`. `d++` on the other hand first assigns the value of `d` back to `d` (thus returning it from a function if used in a return statement) before increasing it by one. Why is this relevant?

Let's keep in mind `fun1(a)` works with a local variable so does not, in fact, alter variable `a`. `++d` increases the local variable by 1, so it's now 2. Then `d++` returns the current value of `d` (2), and then increases the local variable by 1 again -- but this doesnt't get stored anywhere outside of the function `fun1()`. Hence, the variable `b` has now the value 2.

```
c = fun2(b);
```

is a different case, though. Here, we pass a reference to the variable b into the function. So `++d` doesn't just increase the value of a local variable but instead increases the value of `b`, it's now 3. `d++` returns this value to c (so it gets assigned 3), but **also** increases `b` by 1 again to 4. Why? Because `d` is a reference to `b`.

Our ultimate values are hence: `a = 1`, `b = 4`, `c = 3`, and 1 + 4 + 3 = 8.

Comment: When we called the first function (fun1) and ++d was assigned to b we got 2, it was increased by one (3 in the result), but the value of 3 wasn't stored anywhere, so the result remained 2. After the second function (fun2) was called, the b value after a couple of steps was incremented from 2 into 4. So it means that this time the value of 4 was stored due to b being a reference?

Comment: @Daniel4 pretty much. The first answer got edited to elaborate on this subject too. But basically, d++ (post increment) first returns the value of d, then increments it. in fun1(int d) this only increases the liable d. In fun2(int &d) it increases the referenced variable, b.